# User access levels in codignetor

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating project using codignetor 2.0.2. I have four types of users and each can access a different set of pages. How can I do this in codignetor ?

I have users as -

1. *Superadmin* : can access all pages
2. *Admin* : can access only a admin section of site and don't have access to user's section
3. *User* : can access reports only
4. *Visitor* : limited access to reports

Answer (score 1):

Check some authorization libraries with some basic priviliges. You will have then database structure and some examples. For example Tank auth.

Most of the time after user log in you adding to session his group_id and in controllers you check if that group can access that page.

like :

```
if($this->session->userdata('group_id')!=1){
   $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Permission denied');
   redirect('/');
}else{
   //show page
}
```

Comment: As far as I know Tank Auth doesn't handle level acces for users... at least the version being the last one 2 months ago (can't check which one right now) but with some modifications you can work it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries already.
You can use that..

[DX_Auth](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/DX_Auth)

[Redux_Auth](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Redux_Auth)

[Tank_Auth](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Tank_Auth)